# dc.js time series format

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm new to dc.js and I've been trying to create a time series data along with other charts I would eventually cross-filter as well. The graph plots just fine but the data doesn't show up. here is what the data looks like:

```
   month,day_of_week,hour,day,date,geo
    Jan,Thursday,2,1,1/1/15,"33.87865278,-87.32532778"
    Jan,Thursday,22,1,1/1/15,"34.91044167,-86.90870833"
    Jan,Thursday,1,1,1/1/15,"32.14200556,-85.75845556"
     .
     .
     .
   Dec,Saturday,0,4,12/19/15,"31.43981389,-85.5103"
```

I've tried to plot a time series based on the 'date' column and my approach is as follows:

```
d3.csv("hwy.csv", function(data) {
          drawMarkerSelect(data);
    var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%m/%d/%Y');
         data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.dates = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
            d.dateRange = d3.time.month(d.dates);
         });
      });
 function drawMarkerSelect(data) {
      var xf = crossfilter(data);
      var all = xf.groupAll();

trialChart = dc.lineChart(".trial .trial-line");
var trial = xf.dimension(function(d){ return d.dateRange; }); 

var trialGroup = trial.group();

trialChart
        .dimension(trial)
        .group(trialGroup)
        .height(120)
        .width(900)
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2014, 12, 01), new Date(2015, 11, 31)]))
        .xUnits(d3.time.months);

---Other Charts here as well --- 

     dc.renderAll();
```

As of now, this code returns empty chart with x and y bars. I want the total count of cases for each day on y axis and the corresponding date on the x axis.

Your time and support is appreciated!

Comment: Please add the `dc.js` tag. A lot of D3 coders, including me, will not answer a D3 question if it is about DC.

Comment: Got it. I actually thought I put dc.js instead. The issue I'm having anyways most likely has to do with d3.time.format.

Comment: Yes, I see. Since DC uses D3 internally, *everything* in DC has to do with D3. However, the same way I don't like when the JavaScript "gurus" answer a D3 question (because D3 has its own particularities), DC users don't like when D3 coders answer a DC question. Every single time I tried to answer a DC question with a pure D3 solution someone came and said *"this is not the way we do in DC"*. Thus, I don't answer DC questions anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. It's possible that your format doesn't match your dates. `%Y` means YYYY and you probably want `%y` given your data. Can you put together a working example on JSFiddle or a similar site?